# How to add the id of the row being selected in dataTables's columns

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I have JSON data coming from the database in this form,

```
0: {taught_id: "11", course_name: "English", grade_name: "2", section_name: "A", teacher_name: "Ali Khalil"}
1: {taught_id: "6", course_name: "Science", grade_name: "2", section_name: "A", teacher_name: "Talha Ayub"}
2: {taught_id: "8", course_name: "Science", grade_name: "7", section_name: "A", teacher_name: "Talha Ayub"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am creating a dataTable using AJAX and this JSON data, in the following code,

```
function show_assigned_table()
    {
      $.ajax({
          url: "action.php", 
          type: "POST", 
          data: {action:"view_assigned_course_table"}, 
          dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
          $('#assign_table').dataTable({
            data: data, 
            columns: [
            {'data': 'course_name'},
            {'data': 'teacher_name'},
            {'data': 'grade_name'},
            {'render': function(data){
              return '<a id="replace_teacher" data-value = '+taught_id+' class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" href="">Replace</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="remove_teacher" data-value = '+taught_id+' class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="">Delete</a>';
            }},
            
            ]
          });

        },
        error: function(e)
        {
          alert("no");
        }
      });
    }
```

In my dataTable code, I am creating two buttons with the name "Replace" and "Delete".... Both of them have a property "data-value" in which I want to store the "taught_id" of the row for which they are called.. Like, if they are clicked for first row, then data-value should have "11" in it (as seen from the JSON data).
But this doesn't seem to work... How can I do that?

Just for reference, this is one of the codes, following is a code for "Delete" button.

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove_teacher", function(e){
var id = $(this).data('value');
e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
  url: "action.php", 
  type: "POST", 
  data:{action: "Remove_Assigned_Teacher", id: id}, 
  success:function(response)
  {
    response = response.trim(); 
    console.log(response);
    if (response == 'ok')
    {  
      alert("Teacher has been removed from the course successfully!"); 
      $('#assign_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }
      
    else 
      alert("Error occured"); 
  }
    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in the render function. For details take a look to [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). The number of parameters are wrong. The right ones are:

```
function render( data, type, row, meta )
```

Therefore, your **taught_id** is **row.taught_id**.

You cannot duplicate IDs. They must be unique. In order to solve this other issue you can combine the id with **meta.row** parameter.

The snippet:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "taught_id": "11",
        "course_name": "English",
        "grade_name": "2",
        "section_name": "A",
        "teacher_name": "Ali Khalil"
    },
    {
        "taught_id": "6",
        "course_name": "Science",
        "grade_name": "2",
        "section_name": "A",
        "teacher_name": "Talha Ayub"
    },
    {
        "taught_id": "8",
        "course_name": "Science",
        "grade_name": "7",
        "section_name": "A",
        "teacher_name": "Talha Ayub"
    }
];
function show_assigned_table() {
    /*
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:63342/StackOverflow/1.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"view_assigned_course_table"},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            */
            $('#assign_table').dataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    {'data': 'course_name'},
                    {'data': 'teacher_name'},
                    {'data': 'grade_name'},
                    {'render': function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return '<a id="replace_teacher' + meta.row + '" data-value = ' + row.taught_id +
                                ' class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" href="">Replace</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="remove_teacher' +
                                meta.row + '" data-value = ' +
                                row.taught_id + ' class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="">Delete</a>';
                    }}
                ]
            });
    /*
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("no");
        }
    })
    */
}
$(document).on("click", "[id^=remove_teacher]", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('value');
    console.log('taught_id --> ' + id);
    /*
    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{action: "Remove_Assigned_Teacher", id: id},
        success:function(response)
        {
            response = response.trim();
            console.log(response);
            if (response == 'ok')
            {
                alert("Teacher has been removed from the course successfully!");
                $('#assign_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }

            else
                alert("Error occured");
        }
    });
    */
});


show_assigned_table();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>


<table id="assign_table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Makes total sense! Thank you so much for this, couldn't find it anywhere else like this... Really helped and gave a new concept as well!